# Global Queuing/Execution Limits in Nextflow

Tags: docker, groovy, azure-devops, dsl, nextflow

I am experimenting with the Nextflow DSL2 syntax for writing pipelines - I understand that I can use Nextflow Configuration Files to set the maximimum number of concurrent intra-pipeline operations, i.e. processes and the like using the "queueSize" parameter.

However, I am looking at automating execution of differing nextflow pipelines in a variety of executors (likely local/Docker, AWS and Azure) via a basic command API.

Is it possible, or indeed necessary to limit the number of concurrent pipeline executions (i.e. when running the `nextflow run` command in different working directories), and does this vary depending on the executor?

Can it be managed from some external/global configuration?

Comment: Usually it's not necessary to limit the number of concurrent pipeline executions. You might be able to set a limit using [Nextflow Tower](https://cloud.tower.nf/).